# Is there any other option for authenticate using auth0 in third party cookie disabled browsers (safari or brave browser )?

Tags: reactjs, authentication, auth0

I,m trying to login safari and brave browser in my react web application using auth0, but it does not allow the redirect uri to third party requests.I also tried using `custom domain` in auth0, but it does not work.

Comment: Did you try adding your redirect uri to "Allowed Callback URLs" in Auth0 Application settings?

Comment: Yes, I did , but it does not work in safari only.

Comment: you can switch to Unviersal login to avoid CORS issue. https://auth0.com/docs/cross-origin-authentication

Answer (score 0):

A great step in diving towards a solution is tracing the network calls in this type of sitatuion. This can be done by gathering a HAR file and be sure to select "Preserve log" to catch redirects from there you can see where the exact breakdown is. If you are leveraging custom domains, this is a paid feature with Auth0 which would enable Support to dive deeper into what you are facing. Overall, we need more details about what is going on and the errors you are seeing come across. Thanks!

https://auth0.com/docs/troubleshoot/har

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this as auth0 uses third-party cookies for login can be bypassed using this approach.
[Invalid token, state does not match - Auth0 Error Safari only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70359943/invalid-token-state-does-not-match-auth0-error-safari-only/71032503#71032503)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31064047)