# Invalid token, state does not match - Auth0 Error Safari only

Tags: javascript, reactjs, authentication, safari, auth0

while using parseHash function in Auth0 library in safari I am getting error [image]

Same code is working fine in chrome. what can be possibly done to resolve this issue?

```
handleAuthentication = (onSuccessCallback, onErrorCallback) => {
    console.log('handle auth', this.authservice);
    this.authservice.parseHash((err, authResult) => {
      console.log('authresult inside', authResult, 'error', err);
      if (authResult && authResult.accessToken && authResult.idToken) {
        this.setSession(authResult, onSuccessCallback);
      } else if (err) {
        // onErrorCallback();
      }
    });
  };
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After lots of research and article exploration, I finally found a solution to this issue.
As auth0 is unable to access *state* and *nonce* parameters which are required for forwarding to check login details therefore we can manually add it for the authentication flow to work without any issue.

```
login = () => {
    this.authservice.authorize(
      {
        nonce: ${randomString},
        state: ${randomString},
      }
    );
  }

handleAuthentication = (onSuccessCallback, onErrorCallback) => {
  this.authservice.parseHash(
    {nonce: ${randomString}, state: ${randomString},
      (err, result) => {
        // some code
       }
     );
   };
```

Hope it works for you too!!